# sql select count

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables: calls and attachments and I want to display everything that's in the calls table but also display whether a call has attachments, - by determining if there is an attachment record with a call_id in it. Maybe there is attachments, maybe there isn't.

**calls**
call_id
title
description

**attachments**
attach_id
attach_name
call_id

If I write:

```
select call_id, title, description from calls
```

to give me a list of all calls....

How can I also include whether this call record has an attachment(s) or not?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an outer join to accomplish this:

```
SELECT c.call_id, title, description, attach_name
FROM calls c
LEFT OUTER JOIN attachments a ON c.call_id = a.call_id
```

The above will display (NULL) for the attach_name if no attachment is found.  You can use ISNULL() to supply a default value if no attach_name is found, such as:

```
SELECT c.call_id, title, description, 
    ISNULL(attach_name, '(No attachment)') as attach_name
FROM calls c
LEFT OUTER JOIN attachments a ON c.call_id = a.call_id
```

Comment: I dont know the outer join construct very well so I have a question: what this query returns if a call has more than an attachment? Does it duplicate the first three fields or .... ? thanks!

Comment: @Lorenzo - yes, it will duplicate the first three columns, and show one attachment per row.  If you want a single record with the count of attachments, your answer is the way to go, although you'll need to change your query to an outer join as well.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: Thanks. +1 for helping on this :)

Comment: Hey, I got the first example here to work with a slight modification:

Comment: SELECT c.call_id, title, description, count(attach_id)  
FROM calls c  
LEFT OUTER JOIN attachments a ON c.call_id = a.call_id  
group by c.call_id,title,description

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.call_id, a.title, a.description, count(b.attach_id)
from calls a, attachments b
where a.call_id = b.call_id
group by a.call_id, a.title, a.description
union all
select distinct a.call_id, a.title, a.description, 0
from calls a, attachments b
where not exists (select call_id from calls c where c.call_id = a.call_id)
```

this will give a count of attachments for every call with the same title and description

Comment: Lorenzo, this query returns the calls and includes a column(count of attachments) if there is an attachment..but not if there is no attachments?

Comment: It always return the fourth column. Its value is zero if there are no attachments or the number of related attachments if there is at least one

Comment: I am sorry for my english: it returns the exact number of attachments for every call (zero or a number)

Comment: you're english is great:). ok, for me it returns just the calls that have atachments and the number of related attachments. It's not returning calls that have no attachments i.e. there is no attachment record with a matching call _id. hmmm...

Comment: @Lorenzo -- not exactly; your query only counts records where the call ID exists in **both** the Calls table and Attachments table, so if a call has no attachments, it won't return a count.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer edit for including the calls without attachments

Comment: @Lorenzo - Like I suggested above, I strongly suggest you look into OUTER JOINs for your query instead of using a WHERE clause to join your tables; the UNION query is totally overkill.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I have no problem with outer join and with your answer. The only thing is that @thegunner has to write more code to inspect all the call id in a loop. That's why I wrote my old fashioned query

Comment: @Lorenzo - that new edited answer is still giving the same result as before - calls with no attachments are not returned.

Comment: @thegunner: it's very strange. the second query that is part of the union returns only the calls with no attachments. i have tried the query changing table names